# Apache reverse proxy access control

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache reverse proxy that is currently reverse proxying for a few sites. 
However i am now going to be adding a new site (lets call it newsite.com) that should only be accessible by certain IP's. Is this doable using Apache as a reverse proxy?

I use VirtualHosts for the sites that are being proxyied. I have tried using the Allow/Deny directives in combination with the Location statements. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
Servername newsite.com   
<Location http://newsite.com>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from x.x.x.x
</Location>
<IfModule rewrite_module>
 RewriteRule ^/$ http://newsite.internal.com [proxy]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried configuring allow/deny specicaily for the site in the Proxy directives, for example

```
<Proxy http://newsite.com/>
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from x.x.x.x
</Proxy>
```

I still have this definition for the rest of the proxied sites however.

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

No matter what i do it seems to be accessible from any where. Is this because of the definition for all other proxied sites. Is there an order to which it applies Proxy directives. I have had the newsite one both before and after the * one, and also within the VirtualHost statement.

Answer (score 5):

You are using **ServerName** and **ServerAlias** for matching **newsite.com.**

You should **NOT** use for a reverse proxy configuration the directive:

```
<Proxy whatever>
```

You should use:

**For apache 2.2:**

```
<Location />
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from x.x.x.x
</Location>
```

**For apache 2.4:**

```
<Location />
   <RequireAny>
       Require             ip x.x.x.x/255.255.255.0
       Require ...
   </RequireAny>
</Location>
```

After doing the Authz, you simply should do a ProxyPass, and the ProxyPassReverse (for the 302,301 redirects):

```
ProxyPass /  http://newsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse /  http://newsite.com/
```

Take in mind that with this you need to add newsite.com to your /etc/hosts or that dns should resolve the host in the url. You may also use IP address only but you should instruct the httpd server that Preserves the "Host:" header with:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Answer (score 1):

had a similar problem today; Was related to how the wildcard matching is done, I think it uses the full URL: in my case I had

```
<Proxy /jira*>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /jira https://myhost.com
```

and this did not work. Site was accessible from anywhere. I tried a couple of things and found a working version:

```
<Proxy *jira*>
```

So in your case try with

```
<Proxy http://newsite.com*>
```

to make sure apache matches that url.

Comment: depreciated - this solution is not working with apache2.4

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername newsite.com

    <Proxy *>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from x.x.x.x
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /  http://newsite.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://newsite.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does this do, and why does it to it?

Comment: That's a reverse proxy that's only accessible by a certain IP (to be defined by substituting the 'x' in _Allow from x.x.x.x_).

Comment: depreciated - is not working since apache2.4