# Apache reverse proxy location based access control not working

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm running a small web server with Ubuntu 12.05.5 LTS and Apache 2.2.22 and ran into this problem recently:

For an IIS server on a virtual machine I have the following reverse proxy config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on

    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        allow from 192.168.
        allow from 10.8.0
    </Directory>

    ...

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On

    SSLProxyEngine on
    <Location /AutodeskDM>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.
        ProxyPass https://10.8.0.131/AutodeskDM
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.8.0.131/AutodeskDM
    </Location>

    <Location /autodeskdm>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.
        ProxyPass https://10.8.0.131/autodeskdm
        ProxyPassReverse https://10.8.0.131/autodeskdm
    </Location>

....

</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly well and only allows connections from the 192.168. subnet, as expected.

Now when I use the same config minus SSLProxyEngine on and http instead of https in the ProxyPass directives, I get the following error:

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://10.8.0.131/AutodeskDM/
```

If I add

```
Allow from 127.0.
```

it works of course, but access is granted from anywhere.

Playing with the Proxy directive, as suggested elsewhere (e.g. [Apache reverse proxy access control](https://serverfault.com/questions/130815/apache-reverse-proxy-access-control)) has no effect either.

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.
</Proxy>
```

Still allows access from anywhere.

What am I missing here? Is this expected behaviour? If so, why is it different with and without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

As always, another program was getting in the way. I have OpenVPN listening on port 80 and proxying http requests to apache on port 8080. So, naturally, http requests look like they're coming from localhost to apache.